# Harddisk with Thunderbolt V2 - Backup with Time Machine (OS X)

Tags: hard-disk, thunderbolt, backup

I am looking for an external harddisk for backup my MacBook Pro (with Time Machine) and I saw there are already "packed" configurations (combos) like theses:

- [**LaCie Rugged** Thunderbolt](http://www.lacie.com/ch/de/products/mobile-storage/rugged-thunderbolt/)
- [**Transcend** StoreJet 300 portable storage for Mac](http://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-678)
- [**Buffalo** MiniStation™ Thunderbolt](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/portable-hard-drives/portable-hard-drives/ministation-thunderbolt)
- [**WD** PassPort Pro](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=1240#Tab3)

They all seems to be in Thunderbolt Version 1, and I found nothing that was Thunderbolt Version 2.

Because with these combos I cannot really choose the hard drive inside (I tend to prefer the 7200 rpm) and all the above seems to be in 5400 (or unspecified) I am also interested for a hard drive case which has the same features (SATA 3Gb) and Thunderbolt V2.

Where I live (Switzerland) I found only this reference [**Delock** 42490](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/product/delock-42490-25-thunderbolt%E2%84%A2-sata-drive) but it seems to be in Thunderbolt V1 only.

The question I am asking : is there any hard drive case (or combos) with Thunderbolt V2 interface?

Optionally can you recommends some alternatives by answering these questions:

- Is USB 3.0 or Thunderbolt V1 performance enough for backing up 500GB with Time Machine?
- Is a  5400 rpm hard drive fast enough (if I do not want to let my computer making the backup for the whole night)

Comment: Even 500 GB for a 7200 rpm hard drive is a lot to handle...

Comment: Ok, the harddisk is not full, and Time Machine as fas as I know uses differentials to make the backup. But 7'200 is my usual standard (for a decent budget). I just need some feedback from people using Apple TimeMachine as well.

Comment: A while back, I used to use Time Machine to store a couple backups (I don't have the need now). I can't think of something off the top of met head, but using USB 3, or Thunderbolt are both good actions, as they allow for fast speeds.

Comment: Whats your budget?

Comment: more or less like the four products mentionned ... but no more than 250$. If such devices exists but at higher price, I will probably use usb3 or thunderbolt v1 instead. The passport Pro is a bit over my specification as I only need one harddisk as this is mainly for backuping the OS itself (I have already a NAS RAID 1 for the file backups)

Comment: Thunderbolt V1 has a theoretical throughput of 10gbps (1.25GB/s), more than enough to handle backups to a 7200RPM Drive. Unless you were backing up to a PCIe SSD or something, I wouldn't be worried about your interface (USB 3.0, USB 3.1, Thunderbolt 1, Thunderbolt 2) bottlenecking your transfer speeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went for a WD MyPassport Ultra 3Tb for a reasonable price (~160$) and I can say it works very nicely and fast enough for the OSX Time Machine.

I would definitely recommend that external hard disk for doing backups of your machine (OSX TimeMachine but surely will be good for Windows machines as well).